# conversion of the input source to meaniful data in android

Tags: android

i want to ask about that can we convert the input source type data in android. my prob is here that i get the data from the url not in tags form. i fetch output in the inputsource type. after that i want to parse the data in meaniful form is this possible or not?

if this possible then how can i implement?

plz help

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand your question properly. But if you want to convert your inputstream into a string you can do something like this

```
 public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        if (is != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } else {        
            return "";
        }
    }
```